# CC Option in Contribution - Email Receipt

Tags: contributions, receipts

I need my Receipt to be CC'd to specific (Sponsor of the user) whenever I email my receipt to the actual user - How do I achieve this?

Note: each user will have a different sponsor

Is their a way I can do ?

Or do I have to add CC option in the Form ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use CiviRules (along with the added extension Email API to enable CiviRules to send emails) not sure though. I don't think CiviCRM provides you facility to choose cc or bcc when sending receipt from offline contribution form(you can add extension and implement buildform and altermailparams hook). However you could achieve this by doing some manual process

1. Create contribution and don't send receipt.
2. Find contribution and select contribution, use 'Print receipt' action
3. Download the receipt
4. Use Email to activity to send email with receipt as attachment.

Cheers

Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like a Relationship set up (or contact reference field) so that there is a connection between the Donor and the Sponsor then an extension could probably automate this.

Without knowing your full workflow/specs the other thing to confirm you know about so you can rule it out is the PCP - Personal Contribution Page - which is very much designed so that donations for a specific cause/case can be channelled through someone like a sponsor